# symony4 get a form collection prototype with empty data

Tags: forms, symfony

For ajax purpose, I want to access to the form prototype of a collection. I can get it if there is data in the collection. But if the collection is empty data-prototype return an empty string.

How I can return the prototype even if the collection is still empty?

The form field:

```
        ->add('colors', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => JnTestColorColorType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'required'=>false,
            'prototype'=>true
        ))
```

The view:

```
    {% if  form.colors is defined %}
    <h3>Colors</h3>
    <ul class="colors" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.colors.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
   {# iterate over each existing tag and render its only field: name #}
   {% for color in form.colors %}
    <li>{{ form_row(color.color) }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @Philippe-B- remark

> Have you tried rendering the collection field all at once to see if that makes any difference ?

I need to render all field at once to get the prototype in my view!

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items), there are two ways to render the data-prototype attribute :

- Automatically, by rendering the collection field all at once ( `form_row(form.emails)` ).
- Manually, by using the form variables ( `data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.emails.vars.prototype)|e }}"` ).

In both cases the prototype should be rendered regardless of the underlying data.

Comment: @Phillipe-B- Thanks for your response but in my  In my case it really depend if there is or not datas. Within datas, the prototype is correctly set. With no data, data-prototype=""

Comment: Have you tried rendering the collection field all at once to see if that makes any difference ?